# A self-unsure portrait

Tags: visual

[image]

**The portrait cannot tell whether fragment X or Y belongs at
  the ? question mark.**
   
**Can you?**
**How is it a “self-portrait”?**


Let’s say this painting is encountered amid the shadows in
[Mortin Myes’ Second Cryptic Gallery](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/46796/mortin-myes-second-cryptic-gallery)
but, despite its caption, is not a likeness of the artist.
The maze-like tilted area represents an infinite planar pattern
that repeats in many ways yet not entirely,
with shading to help distinguish
two types of recurrent 3×4 rectangles.
(The undecided rectangle at the ? question mark has
 ambiguous checkered shading.)
Horizontal lines decorate loose ends
where the displayed pattern is cropped.

That maze-like pattern indirectly represents a hidden image
with all the answers, if understood.
Some **hinty** practice sketches,
slightly misordered,
demonstrate the artist’s portrayal technique
and the infinite test patterns they indirectly represent
and secretly convey.
Note that blankness conveys a checkerboard-like result,
whereas one of the nonblank patterns
produces a similar but shifted result.

[image]

Everything pertinent is diagrammatic,
with no letters, numbers or colors to consider.
The most you need to solve the self-portrait is something to draw with,
not even electronic
as the solution can readily be described in words.

**Bonus** / **bounty question:**
What mythical creature
(yes, being bonus, a certain creature I happen to be thinking of)
can be discovered in the selfie’s undisplayed pattern extension?

Comment: Honoured to have inspired a puzzle! Which, by the looks of it, seems a fair bit more difficult than mine... I have a few theories but they don't quite fit together yet. A little 'fract'ured perhaps.

Comment: There are already a fragment (with 3 colored cells) at the question mark place. Is it there just to show whether we don't know if the fragment is colored or not and we can just ignore it or it is there for a reason?

Comment: Also what does "(This one)" mean ? Does it really mean that 5th sketch in second row is matched with 5th sketch in 3rd row? Looks like 5th should be matched with 1st.

Comment: Right on both counts, @klm123: The ambiguous checkered shading is meant to show that the area around the **?** question mark has as-yet unknown shading. The 5th sketch is aligned correctly because the top row patterns represent the bottom row patterns in a secret way. Will try to clarify these in the statement.

Comment: So, if all 5 bottom pictures are randomly placed, what does arrows mean then and why one arrow is separated from the other 4? And what does text "(This one)" mean?

Comment: Thanks again for helping clarify this, @klm123, the test pattern sketches are now presented more directly, without parenthetical statements such as "(This one)"

Comment: Bounty question seems like Zvabgnhe(rot13)

Comment: All of a sudden I can't think of anything _but_ (what you said), @bleh, good one! (Was a different creature in mind at the time, though, related to the shape of the labyrinth rather than its occupant.)

Answer (score 1):

> Y. Fill in the background colors and its an inversion of the smaller part. In this instance the white goes with the borders/lines and the blue goes with the blank space or corridor looking area.

---

**Too-much-for-a-comment interjection by this puzzle’s poser**

This answer seems to hinge on an astute observation about the shading pattern.
Here is what I think "fill in the background colors" means,
and a flip of Y that resembles the result.

> [image]

And here is what I think "fill in" and "inversion" mean together,
and a rotated flip of Y that resembles the result.

> [image]

Comment: Actually just the first part, no need to rotate Y 90 degrees. If you zoom in on any one of the smaller grid sections, which are all identical, you will notice that the background blue color of the entire image corresponds to the same pattern as the smaller part. The only difference is that you need to invert the colors and flip the image on the horizontal axis.